# Does the pdu of Delivery Intent contain the phone number of person to whom SMS was send?

Tags: android, pdu

I am trying to find out the phone number of the person to whom SMS was send from the PDU of `Intent` in the `onReceive()` of delivery broadcast receiver like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ThizLog.d(TAG, "Inside onReceive");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
        sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }
    for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
        // Verify if the message came from our known sender
        ThizLog.d(TAG,"!!! " + msg.getOriginatingAddress());

    }
    switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            // SMS delivered
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            /*
            *  SMS not delivered, show SMS_NOT_DELIVERED_MESSAGE
            */
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, SMS_NOT_DELIVERED_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            // shows toast on left top corner increase the zero value to
            // slide it right and down
            //toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

but this resulted in the following error

```
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.abc.mnp.xyz.DeliveredSMSReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2827)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:126)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2088)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.abc.mnp.xyz.DeliveredSMSReceiver.onReceive(DeliveredSMSReceiver.java:37)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2816)
02-04 03:19:34.008: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    ... 10 more
```

It is possible, native SMS app of Android does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not getting the pdu correctly from the received intent.  It'll be a single pdu under the extra key 'pdu' rather than an array.

Try this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String pdu=intent.getStringExtra("pdu");

    ...
}
```